# MS-Access cant find unique index for the ref field of the primary table

Tags: sql, ms-access

This is my task... please help!

Set up Referential Integrity between the sec0808_departments table and the
sec0808_employees table. The sec0808_depatrments table contains a list of all the valid values of the dept_code field.

**sec0808_departments design view**
[image]

**sec0808_employees design view**
[image]

Here is my code:

```
alter table sec0808_departments
add constraint fk_sec0808_departments_dept_code
foreign key(dept_code)
references sec0808_employees(dept_code);
```

Here is the error:

[image]

Thank you for any assistance!
Best :-)

Answer (score 0):

Simply switch the tables in [`ALTER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/alter-table-statement-microsoft-access-sql) command to assign the foreign key in the *Employees* table referencing the *Department* table's primary key. Right now you are attempting to add a foreign key to *Departments* when it already maintains a primary key!

```
alter table sec0808_employees
add constraint fk_sec0808_departments_dept_code
foreign key(dept_code)
references sec0808_departments(dept_code);
```

This way *Departments* (unique `dept_code` on each row) to *Employees* (potentially repeating `dept_code` for employees who share same department) make a one-to-many relationship.